# Prove: if $|A|\leq|B|$, then $|\mathcal{P}(A)| \leq |\mathcal{P}(B)|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove: if $|A|\leq|B|$, then $|\mathcal{P}(A)| \leq |\mathcal{P}(B)|$

I am very lost at how to start the proof (other than the obvious, defining an injection from $\mathcal{P}(A)$ to $\mathcal{P}(B)$).

Comment: Recall that the cardinality of the power set of A is $2^{|A|}$

Comment: Any mapping $f:A\to B$ gives a mapping $P(f) : P(A) \to P(B)$. Do you know how?

Comment: @Jazzachi Yes, that would be a good way... but it's not allowed here unfortunately ;)

Comment: @JohnMa Never heard...

Comment: Hint: you want to prove that if $f:A \to B$ is an injective, then the induced power set map $f^{*}:\mathcal{P}(A) \to \mathcal{P}(B)$ is injective.

Comment: If $f: A\to B$ and $C$ is a subset of $A$, how do you make a subset in $B$?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: Nitpicking here, but the map you want for this proof is the direct image map $f_*$, not the preimage map $f^*$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an injection $\phi:A\to B$ you have that $\phi$ is a bijection to $\phi(A)\subseteq B$. Now if you have a subset $X$ of $A$ then $\phi(X)$ is a subset of $\phi(A)$ and therefore a subset of $B$.

This means that $\mathcal P\phi(A)\subseteq \mathcal P B$. Therefore $|\mathcal P A| = |\mathcal P\phi(A)| \le |\mathcal P B|$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f : A \to B$. Given a subset $U \subseteq A$, its image
$$f[U] = \{ f(x) \mid x \in U \} = \{ y \in B \mid y=f(x) \text{ for some } x \in U \}$$
is a subset of $B$. Prove that if $f$ is injective, then so is the map $U \mapsto f[U]$.

Comment: what does this prove in this context?